# Setting font type for x and y ticks in subplots matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I am having issues setting up the x and y ticks font type to "Times New Roman". Here is my code below:

```
font = {'fontname':'Times New Roman'}

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3, figsize=(20,12))
axes[0,0].get_xticklabels(**font)
axes[0,0].get_yticklabels(**font)
```

However, this command is not resetting the font type to the font I would like it to be. The titles for the x and y axis and labels will set the font type based off the **font argument. Can someone point me to the right command to fix this issue please? Thank you for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `fontname` for each of the `xticklabels` and `yticklabels` for each axes.

You can get the tick labels using [`get_xticklabels`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xticklabels) and [`get_yticklabels`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_yticklabels). Then you want to set the [`fontname`](http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_fontname) property of the resulting [`Text`](http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) objects.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fontname = 'Times New Roman'

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3, figsize=(10,6))

for ax in axes.flatten():
    labels = ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels()
    [label.set_fontname(fontname) for label in labels]
```

[image]